# SQL Datatype error: Can't input characters into SQL table's column

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

```
mysql> insert into oee (ID_NO,S_NO,START_TIME,END_TIME,PASSFAIL) VALUES (67,85,345643,345633,P);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'P' in 'field list'
```

The above command works if i input an integer instead of a character.
See:

```
mysql> insert into oee (ID_NO,S_NO,START_TIME,END_TIME,PASSFAIL) VALUES (67,85,345643,345633,43);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from oee;
+-------+------+------------+----------+----------+
| ID_NO | S_NO | START_TIME | END_TIME | PASSFAIL |
+-------+------+------------+----------+----------+
|    16 | 1233 | 00:23:23   | 00:01:23 | 2323     |
|    23 | 35   | 00:00:43   | 00:02:34 | 234      |
|    67 | 85   | 34:56:43   | 34:56:33 | 43       |
+-------+------+------------+----------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So i checked if the datatype of the column was an integer and found out that there was no problem with the datatype. 
Here is how i found about the datatype:

```
mysql> SELECT DATA_TYPE
    -> FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    -> WHERE
    ->      TABLE_NAME = 'OEE' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'PASSFAIL';
+-----------+
| DATA_TYPE |
+-----------+
| char      |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Error message is:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'P' in 'field list'

What is going wrong?

Comment: `insert into oee (ID_NO,S_NO,START_TIME,END_TIME,PASSFAIL) VALUES (67,85,345643,345633,'P');`  ?

Comment: If it is char, it should be within single quotes. `(67,85,345643,345633,'P')`

Comment: Oops, thank you so much! I was in a hurry and didn't realize that i was making this silly mistake! Also do you know the command for Altering the column datatype in SQL 8? Looks like there is a lot of syntax changes in the newer version.

Comment: So @RomeoSierra has saved the day. The question can be closed.

Comment: @KrishnakumarM *Also do you know the command for Altering the column datatype in SQL 8* - That's a separate question that you should ask separately. Plus, I am pretty sure that there are plenty of answers and tutorials out there, that you could find by simply googling it. :)

Comment: can you provide the output of :    SELECT distinct TABLE_NAME,DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'PASSFAIL';

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really an expert in SQL but since the column is of type char maybe try putting quotes around the value.

```
insert into oee (ID_NO,S_NO,START_TIME,END_TIME,PASSFAIL) VALUES (67,85,345643,345633,'P');
```

Comment: Use single quotes for string literals.

Comment: @jarlh My bad, as I mentions I’m no expert at SQL. Is using single quotes simply a good style choice or is it required?

Comment: Required. Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, e.g. column names with odd characters.

Answer (score 0):

Put single quotes around `P`. If you're inserting chars, you have to put them into single quotes.

Before:

`insert into oee (ID_NO,S_NO,START_TIME,END_TIME,PASSFAIL) VALUES (67,85,345643,345633,P);`

After:

`insert into oee (ID_NO,S_NO,START_TIME,END_TIME,PASSFAIL) VALUES (67,85,345643,345633,'P');`

Comment: `ALTER TABLE oee ALTER COLUMN PASSFAIL <new column definition here>`

Comment: What comes in " <new column definition here> "? Can you give an example? Sorry, I'm really new to SQL

Answer (score 0):

In here you have used p instead of 'P' when inserting the data to your table.
If there is no variable you have declared as P, you can't use P for the insert query.
That's why you can insert 43 as a data.
If you want to insert P to your table use this below query.

`insert into oee (ID_NO,S_NO,START_TIME,END_TIME,PASSFAIL) VALUES (67,85,345643,345633,'P');`